# Wrong order of commands execution in TimerTask.run() (in Android app written in Java)

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I’m writing a simple android app (in Java) that should be able to load a *.txt file and display its content one word at a time every 0.5 second. I’ve managed to put content of a text file into an String array which under each index stores one word. I’m using Timer and TimerTask to display words from the array in a TextView with given interval. To achieve this goal my TimerTask run() method first calls TextViev.setText() method that displays item from the array at current index and then increments index (or so I thought). As it turns out first the index is incremented and then TextViev.setText() method is called (despite the order of commands in overridden run() method of TimerTask). My question is: why commands are executed in this order, and how can I fix it?

```
TimerTask readingTimerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (wordIndex < textArr.length - 1) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvWords.setText(textArr[wordIndex]);
                            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "setText() called. wordIndex: " + String.valueOf(wordIndex));
                        }
                    });
                    wordIndex++;
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "wordIndex incremented. New value of wordIndex: " + String.valueOf(wordIndex));
                } else {
                    stopReading();
                }
            }
        };
mTimer = new Timer();
Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Timer is starting. wordIndex: " + String.valueOf(wordIndex));
mTimer.schedule(readingTimerTask, 100, displayTimeInMs);
```

And the Logcat looks something like this:

```
D/MainActivity: wordIndex in onActivityResult (file loaded): 0
I/MainActivity: Timer is starting. wordIndex: 0
I/MainActivity: wordIndex incremented. New value of wordIndex: 1
I/MainActivity: setText() called. wordIndex: 1
I/MainActivity: wordIndex incremented. New value of wordIndex: 2
I/MainActivity: setText() called. wordIndex: 2
I/MainActivity: wordIndex incremented. New value of wordIndex: 3
I/MainActivity: setText() called. wordIndex: 3
I/MainActivity: wordIndex incremented. New value of wordIndex: 4
I/MainActivity: setText() called. wordIndex: 4
I/MainActivity: wordIndex incremented. New value of wordIndex: 5
I/MainActivity: setText() called. wordIndex: 5
I/MainActivity: Timer has been stopped. wordIndex: 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why are the commands executed in this order?**

When called from a background thread, `runOnUiThread()` does not wait for the commands within `run()` to complete before returning. It arranges for them to execute on a *separate thread*: The UI thread.

I assume that your code snippet is invoked on the UI (or "main") thread. Meanwhile, your `TimerTask` is introducing a second thread: Its internal background worker. IOW, you have created a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Example).

The `wordIndex++` is not *guaranteed* to execute first, under such a condition, but it will usually "win" the race, since it takes a little while for the UI thread to handle the `Runnable`.

**How can I fix it?**

You might not've intended to introduce multiple threads into your program -- that can make things quite complicated, and it is not for novice programmers. You may want to use a [`CountDownTimer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer), instead of a `TimerTask`. That will help you keep everything on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer proved to be very helpful. For now I've moved wordIndex++ command inside the same block of code as setText(), which seems to ensure execution of commands in intended order, but I think I’ll substitute Timer with CountDownTimer as you suggested.